# How To Remove all text after a word from a strings?

Tags: php, replace

how can i remove a word and after that from paragraph ?

e.g :

How To Remove all text after this (test ) word from a strings ?

```
ABC DEF GHEE JUL *test MON ...*
```

i want to remove **test MON ...** from my string

and have just :

```
ABC DEF GHEE JUL
```

Thanks

Comment: There are numerous string functions available to you (http://php.net/ref.strings) - strpos, substr, strcspn, strstr etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split easy

```
$string = "ABC DEF GHEE JUL test MON";
$splitted = explode("test", $string);
$result = $splitted[0]; //ABC DEF GHEE JUL
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be to simply substring:

```
$result = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, 'test'));
```

Comment: This will return an empty string if 'test' is not in `$string`.

Comment: That does not matter. He wanted to shorten strings like `ABC DEF GHEE JUL *test MON ...* `, not `ABC DEF GHEE JUL *MON ...*`.

Comment: That was just an example. Unexpected behavior, like returning an empty string instead of a full string, matters.

Comment: Unexpected behaviour? Oh come on, a simple if statement does fine there if you really need it...

Answer (score -1):

You can create functions and reuse them later, like:

```
$test1=removeAfterFirst("ABC DEF GHEE JUL test MON ...","test ");
// $test1 is "ABC DEF GHEE JUL "

$test2=removeAfterLast("ABC DEF ABC GHE","ABC");
// $test2 is "ABC DEF "
```

The functions:

```
public static function removeAfterFirst($text,$value)
{
    $firstOccurence=strpos($text,$value);
    if($firstOccurence===false)
        return $text;
    return substr($text,0,$firstOccurence);
}

public static function removeAfterLast($text,$value)
{
    $lastOccurence=strrpos($text,$value);
    if($lastOccurence===false)
        return $text;
    return substr($text,0,$lastOccurence);
}
```

Comment: Would you have any good reason why such a trivial task should be pushed to some Static Methods of an undefined Class? You could either write a Rudimentary Function or simply show the basic Algorithm or if you insist on you OOP, provide a complete Class Definition.... doubtfully; the OP may really not need that OOP Route just to do so string replacement operation...

Comment: Any good reason? How about for developers that come after you and want to know what you were doing. While seeing a call to a function named `RemoveAfter...` is instantly understandable, looking at (ugly) `substr`,`strpos` calls is not instantly understandable.

Comment: ***There is no developer coming after this OP for NOT doing string replacement from within a Class***... it is clearly doubtful that even the worst, most nagging Developer could want you to go that far for something so very simple... but perhaps.... (who knows).... ;-)  And for your information, a Good Developer cares only about the Quality, Delivery & Performance of your Code not **YOUR UNIQUE TECHNIQUES OF WRITING CODE...**

Comment: Believe me, that is the way to go. I don't know about your experiences, but if/when you will work in a large company/agency with lots of domain knowledge and code, all trivial tasks are best put in static utility classes and functions. Just trust me on that. :)

Comment: Do you now imagine that someone who cannot do string replacements and who has an SO Reputation of 5... (i mean the OP) works in such an Agency you described? And just as an Aside; even if you work for **god software corporation**, You as a Programmer should know exactly what to do,  where and when: That is called initiative.  Putting commonly used Methods & Functions in a Static Class is Great but not when you have to simply replace a few characters in a 7-Word String....

Comment: No, I do not. But we're not here only to give them fish, but also to teach them HOW to fish themselves. And to answer your Aside: I agree that you should know exactly what to do, where and when. But there is a way to do it better. Always replacing a few characters with multiple lines of code instead of just one or even by calls to functions with ugly regular expressions is just ridiculous. A good code is easily readable by any programmer, not just the one who wrote it. ;)

Comment: OP had wanted and has accepted the simplest solution. Like Einstein said: **When the solution is simple, God is answering.** And by the way, you don't also need to teach a Toddler how to bake his own cake. First he crawls, talks, walks, runs, grows, and ONLY THEN you get him a COOKBOOK... if he dislikes books, BRING HIM TO THE KITCHEN... But certainly not before.... A Programmer (seeing that one is Freshman) starts by introducing Static Methods without Definition — on the assumption a Freshman gets it? That sounds like a Einstein teaching Relativity to a 5 Yr. Old Kid: **Awesome!!!**

Comment: Lastly: How Subjective is that phrase: **A Good Code**! There are no Good and Bad Codes... never were... There were, still are and always will be programmers with peculiar Logic.... and the Results??? You guessed it! Code don't write itself so it should not be qualified. The Programmer writes the Codes... He should be qualified. Code readability is Essential, yet of all the Codes posted here, yours seem sincerely quite peculiar. Yet; quite clearly, every so-called Programmer can read the Codes in all the other Posts with ease... because the longest has just about 4 Lines: **Except Yours ;-)**

Comment: You don't get it: My code is long because it is written as utility functions. That is why there is an example usage below. And in that example, my code is the shortest, easiest to use, and when a new developer comes and goes through thousands of lines of code, when he sees a call to `removeAfter...`, he can instantly move onto the next line. But if he comes to `strpos(..,substr(..,..)`, he must spend ~5 seconds figuring out what it does, and then move on. Imagine spending 5 seconds for each line of code for 1000 lines of code. THAT is BAD code. I would guess you have no experience but school.

Comment: In your idea of coding, we should be coding in assembly, or better yet, in zeros and ones! Why use code that is easier to read for humans when we can code in 1000010101100! :) Have nice day and get some experience working in a development team, not only as a solo programmer. Cheers.

Comment: Are You taking this Personal? Thought experienced Programmers got good sense of Humour:-) Well, as you can see, You are making so much sense now that that even nonsense appears to be wrapped in Poetic Aesthetics which makes you both Smart, Intelligent & Great. What could a Lion possibly have in common with a Sheep? Yet, a Leopard can never change it's spots. **CASE CLOSED!!!** You are Right & You are the Best.....

Comment: My upvote for the effort to construct a code that  seems to work and to compensate an, in my humble opinion, unmeritory downvote. This answer should be at zero at least (my answer was not upvoted yet )

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I upvoted your question, clever solution to use `explode` instead of `substr(strpos))`. Every developer should follow this simple funny rule: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Comment: And what would a Violent Psychopath really do at the worst when he storms your Home? Kill You, right? If one is afraid to DIE, how can such one then LIVE? But then again, who would ever offer a Violent Psychopath a Programming Job? **EVERY DEVELOPER SHOULD...**  If Mozart played like Beethoven....  And so: ***which of these are You: A DEVELOPER, SON, FRIEND, BROTHER, MAN, SMART GUY, GOOD GUY, ETC?*** **A Developer?** ***Could that be truly WHO YOU REALly ARE?*** If You could read between the Lines, You'd clearly see the missing Puzzle-Pieces hidden in plain sight...  ✌✌✌✌✌✌✌

Comment: Get a hold of yourself please, you're embarrassing yourself.

Comment: Embarass? Such a Pity! Which Self do you refer to? He alone can be embarrassed, shamed or affected in anyways who has one thing or the other to gain or lose: someone who has something to protect or hide. Those who have gone beyond their tiny, limited Egos; what else is there for them to gain or lose? How can what affect them? Kill them, strip them naked before the world or do as you wish: yet they'd smile @you (knowing your ignorance). Don't project how you feel on others! It doesn't work that way. Embarrassment are for those who have not been deep down in Hell. **BEEN THERE. DONE THAT!** ;-)

Comment: If you could pause a moment to listen to yourself; you'd see that ironically you are already embarrassed. You are obsessed with being right, being normal & accepted, following rules, etc. People in such limited Boxes can easily be thrown off by the tiniest friction bcos they can't see beyond their boxes & would do everything to control & protect it. Most of them are Control Freaks who can do whatever it takes to protect their limited world & reality. Is your Heart beating faster now? This describes You, right? Yet you can't accept it: You'd fight it to reassert your Box.

Comment: Get a grip, please. This conversation is/was about my provided answer, which is absolutely without any doubt RIGHT. Except that you had a problem with it. I tried to explain it to you and you didn't want to except it. Let's just leave it at that. Or are you mad because your answer has -3 votes? :) And no, I am not that kind of guy that you think I am. I'm like that only while programming, because code it deterministic and cannot be "beyond the box". Also, I respect the one coming in after me and try to code in a way that it is easily humanly readable, and that's the whole point.

Answer (score -3):

You may try something like this:

```
<?php
    $string = "ABC DEF GHEE JUL test MON ...";
    $clean1 = preg_replace("#(\s[a-z]+?).+$#", "", $string);

    var_dump($clean1);  //<== YIELDS: string 'ABC DEF GHEE JUL' (length=16)
```

Comment: Wrong. This works only for this particular example. OP did not say that he always wants everything removed after the first small letter, that was just an example.

Comment: Agreed with the small caps but not meritory of downvote however. Did you turn crazy on this topic? :)